# Minimum feedback vertex set

Tags: algorithms, graphs, approximation, greedy-algorithms

A greedy algorithm for finding a minimum feedback vertex set 
is to  pick and remove a vertex with minimum $w(v)/\delta_H(v)$, where $H$ is the current graph, until there are no more cycles left. (That is, the algorithm looks at the lowest cost per cycle space decreased node picks it and continues to do so as long as the graph continues to have cycles.) What is the approximation guarantee of this algorithm?

Note: $\delta_H(v) = \text{cyc}(H) - \text{cyc}(H-v)$ where
$ \text{cyc}(H) $ is the dimension of the cycle space of $H$.

See also Exercise 6.1 of Vazirani's "Approximation Algorithms".

Comment: Please define your notations.

Comment: What do you think? We expect you to make a serious effort before asking a question. We will not solve your exercise for you.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  is csstackexchange not allow posting exercises?   I can't seem to find solutions to these exercises.

Comment: @HaoS posting exercises is ok, but we expect you to show significant effort. This question looks more like a problem dump which tend to get closed.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus    I don't quite understand what you mean by problem dump    I'm kinda curious as to a counterexample since the 2 approximation looks kind of like a greedy approach  so is it just the lack of a reverse deletion step?  or is there more to the layering technique?

Comment: @Juho  maybe the question is easy and theres something stupid I don't see or I'm misinterpreting the problem but I feel like it's quite interesting because the local ratio method which gives a 2 approximation looks a lot like a greedy method but the book says the greedy method does not give any constant approximation

Comment: @HaoS A problem dump is like a verbatim copy of a textbook exercise. It has nothing to do with whether the problem is easy or not. Our policy is that we are not a homework service. However, if you explain what you have tried and where you got stuck we are happy to help, again regardless of how hard or easy the problem is.

Comment: @Juho  would it help if I said it's not part of a course credit I'm just teaching myself some cs  
I actually have no idea how to go about this problem but find it rather interesting because in the chapter they introduce the local ratio method which is a 2 approximation and this looks very similar but the book says it's not a  constant approx which I find interesting

Comment: @HaoS It's definitely better than just copying and pasting the exercise.